# Join ImageView and TextView drawing a line on the screen by touch

Tags: android, validation, ontouchlistener

I am not sure what method to use for my goal.

I want to make and app for children where they can see images of animals and relate those images with the name of the animals by using they fingers to draw a line between the image and the name.

Should I got the info from `OnTouchListener` and then, what I use to draw the line following the finger, and, at the end, should I create a kind of map with coordinates for right and wrong or maybe I can use the touch listener of the `ImageView` and the `TextView`?

I would apreciate any guidelines.

Thanks.

Comment: Have You tried any method? What problems do You expect with first approach? How many images could be presented the same time? Is it possible to continue drawing the same line after pointer up?

Comment: I am not sure how to relate the line with the ImageView and the TextView. I am suposed to be able to draw on a canvas, ¿right? If the canvas is transparent, my ImageViews and my TextViews could be under the transparent canvas. But I do not know how to relate them (the views) with the onTouch and onKeyUp from the OnTouchListener. Because if the views are under the canvas, how do I connect views and canvas line? And I have not put it all together. Just learn the OnTouchListener, now I am learning to draw the line on the canvas. Next step: relate canvas and views. Any help? Thanks.